# Handwriting font lowcase letters and math

Tags: math-mode, fonts

How can I make the math formular also as handwritten?
And can I make the letters in the handwritten be as written on screen with lower case?

As you can see both g af b are written as G and B.

```
    \documentclass[border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\augiefamily}{%
    \fontfamily{augie}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textaugie}{\augiefamily}



\begin{document}
    
        \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) {$f(x)=b\cdot a^x$};
    \node[scale=0.4, blue] at (2.5,-0.2) {\augiefamily Eksponenten, den uafhængige variabel};
    \node[scale=0.4, orange] at (1.6,-0.6) {\augiefamily Fremskrivningsfaktoren};
    \node[scale=0.4, red] at (1.2,0.5) {\augiefamily Skæring med y-aksen};
    
    \draw[->,red] (0.4,0.5) to[out=180,in=90] (0.27,0.25);
    \draw[->,blue] (1.1,-0.2) to[out=180,in=270] (0.88,0);
    \draw[->,orange] (1,-0.5) to[out=140,in=270] (0.7,-0.15);
            
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I fear that the B and G shape is a font choice...: https://www.dafont.com/augie.font

Comment: Okay, do you no any other font, that looks like this but hvis b and g?

Comment: @JakobKruse Have a look at https://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=603&text=Sk%E6ring

Comment: Thank you, I found "mouly"

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thank you I found the "mouly".  but why is the ( ) not in the same font?

Comment: @JakobKruse The trick below works because beamer does not actually use a math font for letters and digits, but substitutes them from the text font. Other symbols will be taken from a normal math font. If you find a handwritten font which supports math symbols, you could use it with unicode-math instead of this trick...

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz how do I do that with unicode-math??

Comment: @JakobKruse I'm not aware of any handwritten math font, but if you have one: `\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Fira Math}
\begin{document}
$f(x)=b\cdot a^x$
\end{document}`

Comment: Thanks for the help - i found a solution that if I make ( in \text{(} then it will be as the font.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I use https://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=603&page=1&l[]=10&l[]=1&text=Is+there+%E0+%F2+%80+%E6%3F+See+ff+l1+VA+Tl+%BFe%F1e+N%D1%3F to check for completeness (Tahu! is nice, apart for the mirrored "N"...)

Comment: @Rmano ... or you could follow the brilliant plan by David about languages :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to switch to xelatex or lualatex and have `augie` installed as font on your computer, you could do something like this:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

    \documentclass[border=1cm,beamer,crop]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{augie}



\begin{document}
    
        \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) {$f(x)=b\cdot a^x$};
    \node[scale=0.4, blue] at (2.5,-0.2) { Eksponenten, den uafhængige variabel};
    \node[scale=0.4, orange] at (1.6,-0.6) { Fremskrivningsfaktoren};
    \node[scale=0.4, red] at (1.2,0.5) { Skæring med y-aksen};
    
    \draw[->,red] (0.4,0.5) to[out=180,in=90] (0.27,0.25);
    \draw[->,blue] (1.1,-0.2) to[out=180,in=270] (0.88,0);
    \draw[->,orange] (1,-0.5) to[out=140,in=270] (0.7,-0.15);
            
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I do this it comes with the error
"Package fontspec Error: The font "augie" cannot not be found"

Comment: @JakobKruse It needs to be installed as font on your computer. You can get it e.g. from https://www.dafont.com/augie.font How to install the .ttf file will depend on your operating system.

Comment: Why is the ( ) not in the same font???

Comment: see my comment to your question.